# MySQL: How to get Information in Header , Subheader sort of format

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a SQL query to give me information in the following structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa2W2.png)

I am basically trying to create a MySQL Select Query with a sort of subset.

If anyone has any ideas on this please let me know, this is the logic I has in mind

```
SELECT 
device_type
COUNT(devices)
  device_type_class
  COUNT(device_type_class) 
COUNT(Total Devices)
FROM device_type
INNER JOIN dev_type classification
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what scheme you have.

Let me take a wild guess:

You have 'devecie' table with FK to type.id

And you have `device_type` table with id, type and subtype.

```
SELECT
    dt.type,
    dt.subtype,
    COUNT(ds.id)
FROM
    device_type dt
LEFT JOIN
    device ds ON ds.type_id = dt.id
GROUP BY
    dt.type, dt.subtype
;
```